# AppArmor: allow entire disk access

Tags: apparmor

I am using AppArmor to:

- **disable** network for a particular process.

But I do want to:

- **enable** read and write wherever it wants.

I just want to restrict network access, not file access. (If you are curious, the process in question is jupyter, which executes some notebooks written by the user for a hacking competition.)

I am trying to edit `/etc/apparmor.d/xxxxx` to allow that:

```
# Last Modified: Mon May 21 23:47:47 2018
#include <tunables/global>

/home/ricardopdmcruz/.local/bin/jupyter {
  #include <abstractions/base>
  #include <abstractions/python>

  /** rwlkmix,

  /home/ricardopdmcruz/.local/bin/jupyter r,
  /usr/bin/python3.5 ix,

  # block ipv4 acces
  deny network inet,
  # ipv6 
  deny network inet6,
  # raw socket
  deny network raw,
}
```

But the process (jupyter) still complains that it cannot read or write somewhere... Does the order of the configuration file matters?

Comment: You have to post your entire apparmor profile and the error you are getting to debug. What is the point of using apparmor if you are going to write a rule `/** rwlkmix,` , that rule basically gives unrestricted access.

Comment: @Panther The point is to restrict network access, but not file access.

Comment: Still can't debug your problem. Post your apparmor profile and error message in the logs

Comment: Thank you guys for your comments. I have expanded on my post. While answering your comments, I found out what the problem was (see my response below)!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was.

Jupyter (even in shell mode) requires sockets, and that is disabled by my rules.

I think two solutions would have been possible:

1. disable external internet, but allow sockets
2. only use jupyter to convert from .ipynb to .py and then use AppArmor on the python3 interpreter. (I used a copy of the python3 interpreter, not the system's version, to not interfere with the system.)

I have chosen solution #2, because I didn't know how to achieve #1. I tried to remove "deny network raw" and keep "deny network inet", but this also seemed to disable sockets.